# Background audio playback while recording video - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement a feature such that when a video is being recorded in flutter, a selected audio should be playing in the background. I am using the default camera package for recording the video. I would like some guidance in this regard.

Comment: did you come up with a solution?